# What DB better to use for application?

Tags: java, sql, database, application

I want to create program for PC in OS Windows, Mac and Linux. 
Program deal must use big DB with about 12 000 000 items. I need to have text search what is the best technology for that?

Maybe Java  + mongodb? Or PHP + SQLite? Or Java + Sedna? Sphinx + SQLite + ? Or use chm format?

Priority is:

- Speed
- Easy install (as possible less other programs and services )
- Low computer requirements
- Use this program as a server for intranet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql for storing data, lucene for search and memcached/redis/whatever for caching

any mainstream language can handle operating with those

Answer (score 1):

You can choose any one from following options:

1. [MySql](http://www.mysql.com/)
2. [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html)
3. [PostgreSql](http://www.postgresql.org/)

All this can hold a large amount of data. And for searching it also depends on your searching logic or algorithm. So you can try any of above.

Comment: Is any solution with out DB installation?

Answer (score 1):

Try this Thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523765/which-db-should-i-use

Answer (score 1):

I would use [PHP](http://www.php.net/) and [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/). For development environment I would use [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) which works on all three Operating Systems. To manage my database I would use [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php), which have good export - import functions. I've tried this setup on different locations and (to my knowledge) it's fast, smooth install and use scarce computer resources.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL is in my opinion the most stable and professional open source database. its more suited to complex calculations and sorts then a simple grab of 1 table. its come a long way over the last few years and its supported by most major OS's. its much more feature filled and stable then MYSQL. (IN my opinion, please do not flame about this)

Do not use PHP if you need raw speed, PHP is compiled on the go so it will always be slower then other application languages. JAVA and even PYTHON would be faster unless you want to also want to use a reverse proxy.

But that's just for web development, more information is needed to make a more informed decision.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a solution without heavy database installation, SQLite might be a good idea. It can handle big databases, also it can be pretty fast for most operations.

Sure, on big enough sets of data, it probably will not get the same performance as a PostgreSQL. But if you are looking for an easy install, SQLite is definitely what you're looking for. It can be used from C, C++, Java, PHP, just to quote a few.

Only drawback I see, is that buiding you app on a server-client pattern will not be as easy with SQLite as it would be with stuff like MySQL.